# Splitting a string into sub-strings of equal length

Tags: java, string, substring

I'm taking an intro prog class so I am only allowed to use methods of string objects. There is probably other 'prettier' way to solve it but I'm not allowed to use more advanced techniques. Pretend that I have a string "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" I want to split it into different parts of equal length. My attempted solution is below which does not work. It only prints out one part, in this case, "aaa." I'm not sure which string method is the best. I figured substring which be the way to go but not sure on how to implement it correctly.

```
 int splitSize = 5
 String s = "aaabbbcccdddeeefffggghhhiiijjjkkklllmmmnnnooo";
 for (int i = 0; i < s.length() / splitSize; i++) {
    s = s.substring(i, i + 3);
 }
```

Comment: Increment i by the splitSize, not just by 1.

Comment: you need to add splitsize instead of i+3

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume you want your output as an array of strings (you are currently *ignoring* output; another option would be to *print* it). Then you can implement something like

```java
public static String[] split(String s, int splitSize) {
    String[] result = new String[(s.length()+splitSize-1)/splitSize];
    for (int i=0, j=0; i<s.length(); i+=splitSize) {
        result[j++] = s.substring(i, Math.min(s.length(), i+splitSize));
    }
    return result;
}
```

This will return an array with consecutive substrings of `splitSize` characters each, where the last one may be smaller than the rest if it could not be filled in. If you need to even them out, there's something called [Bresenham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm)'s algorithm that does just that (although it is more commonly used for drawing lines)

Notice that `"1".substring(0,3)` throws an exception - you should not try to take a larger substring than is available.

You can avoid using `Math.min` when adding to the result by either using an `if` statement or the ternary operator (`?:`).

Comment: This is really close to what I am trying to achieve. The only thing left is that I want to replace one instance of a character with another. With string I would just use name.replace(" ", ""); is there is method to do the same with an array of type String?

Comment: I tried using `result[j] = result[j].replace("a", "b");` which compiled but it gives me a NullPointerException when I ran the code.

Comment: I got it to work with the exception of one little bug. I used `s[j] = s[j].replace("_", "");`  however after grouping the string into subgroups in the end it gives me a couple of null groups based on the replaced characters. For example `"aaa_bb_bc_cc"` would return the array `[aaa, bbb, ccc, null]` but I want it to return `[aaa. bbb, ccc]`.

Comment: you should then filter *before* the split: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split("aaa_bb_bc_cc".replace("_",""), 3)))` returns `[aaa, bbb, ccc]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this (`s.length()` must be a multiple of `splitSize`).

```
int splitSize = 5;
String s = "aaabbbcccdddeeefffggghhhiiijjjkkklllmmmnnnooo";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length();) {
    System.out.println(s.substring(i, i + splitSize));
    i = i + splitSize;
}
```

Comment: why did you move  `i = i + splitSize;` out of the for-loop?

Comment: @tucuxi, I don't have a  good reason(I just wrote it this way) , may be better readability !.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "count/flag" to keep an eye on string index and split size. check out this code

```
int splitSize = 5
String s = "aaabbbcccdddeeefffggghhhiiijjjkkklllmmmnnnooo";
int count = 0;
String tempString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    String str_atIndex = Character.toString(s.charAt(i));
    if(count < splitSize){
        tempString = tempString + str_atIndex;
        count++;
    }else{
        count = 0;
        System.out.print(tempString);
        tempString = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, you are trying to divide String(s) by an integer(splitSize). It will give you a compile error.

You can try something like this:

```
static void split(int splitSize) {
        String s = "aaaaabbbbbccccc";

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += splitSize) {
            System.out.println(s.substring(i, i+splitSize));
        }
     }
```

Prints:

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
```

If that's what you are looking for. Hope that helps.

Comment: throws exception if I try this with `"aaaaabbbbbcccccx"`

Comment: hmm, thanks for pointing that out. Will have to think something else.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use String's `charAt` method.

```
int splitSize = 5;
String s = "aaabbbcccdddeeefffggghhhiiijjjkkklllmmmnnnooo";

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

    System.out.print(s.charAt(i));

    if ((i + 1) % splitSize == 0) {
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Each character in the string is printed to the console and when the index `i` is divisible with the `splitSize`, it starts a new line.